# Does Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler Support timeDate on Timers?

Tags: eclipse, jbpm, bpmn

I using using the Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler Luna 1.1.3 to build my bpmn file. I am trying to set a boundary timer to expire at a specific time that is saved in ISO 8601 format as a process variable. The Eclipse BPMN2 modeler only provides an option for Interval (timeCycle) or Duration (timeDuration). If I manually update the XML element to timeDate, the timer works as expected.

What is generated

```
<bpmn2:boundaryEvent ...
    <bpmn2:outgoing> ...
    <bpmn2:timerEventDefinition ...
       <bpmn2:timeDuration ...
```

What I need/change to

```
<bpmn2:boundaryEvent ...
    <bpmn2:outgoing> ...
    <bpmn2:timerEventDefinition ...
       <bpmn2:timeDate ...
```

Is there some hidden option/field that I am not seeing or does the modeler not support timeDate element? If it does not, does anyone the location of the official JIRA for the Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler so that I can report this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems timeDate is hidden by default for the jBPM profile.  You can however turn it on in the preferences:
Window -> Preferences -> BPMN2 - Editor - Tool Profiles and for jBPM profile, select the checkbox timerEventDefinition -> TimeDate

Could you please open a bugzilla to enable this by default?
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=BPMN2Modeler

Comment: Thanks @Kris. I submitted the bug. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462070